# Keras Sequential Model Data Preparation: observations of single row

Tags: python, keras, lstm, keras-layer

My data is a matrix of 400k observations, where each observation is a single row of data, 200 elements in length. My output data is 400k 1-hot vectors corresponding to 11 output classes. I would like to format my data for a keras sequential model. (Keras 2.0.4, Python 3)

```
train_values.shape
>>> (400000, 200)

data_labels.shape
>>> (400000, 11)
```

Attempt 1:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape = (200,), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=11, input_dim=100, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_values, train_labels, batch_size=200, epochs=10)
score = model.evaluate(test_values, test_labels, batch_size=200)
```

Error 1:

```
    ----> 3 model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape = (200,), return_sequences=True))

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Attempt 2:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(400000,200))
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape = (200,), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=11, input_dim=100, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_values, train_labels, batch_size=200, epochs=10)
score = model.evaluate(test_values, test_labels, batch_size=200)
```

Error 2:

```
----> 7 model.fit(train_values, train_labels, batch_size=200, epochs=10)
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (400000, 11)
```

Conclusion: Is my error with the input formatting, the calling of my layers, or something else entirely that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Found a working solution:

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(200, output_dim=200))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(num_output_buckets, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])